# Has another character ever observed Deadpool breaking the fourth wall?

Tags: marvel, deadpool

Has it ever happened (in a comic book, or TV show, or movie or anything) where Deadpool breaks the fourth wall and another character responds to it? Whether it's joining in and breaking the fourth wall with him, or being confused by his strange remarks and questioning him, or anything else?

Comment: In the few Deadpool comics I've actually read, it's happened in all of them. I recall a scene where another character responds to his thought bubbles, and he's like "Oops, mixed up my thought and speech bubbles again." And it happened in Marvel: Ultimate Alliance 2. I'm sure you'll get cited actual issues.

Comment: [Here's possibly the first canon instance of Deadpool referring to previous issues of his own comic, while speaking to Bullseye](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/deadpool/images/5/5c/DeadpoolBullseye.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120723154721) (Deadpool vol. 1 #28, I believe)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There are multiple times to prove that some shenanigans were going on. Let's dig into some of the comics:

- The time when he was narrating himself and he got caught, again:

  [image: Domino catches Deadpool narrating himself and says: "Deadpool! Are you narrating yourself again? We talked about that, remember?" to which Deadpool replies: "Was that out load? I thought it was up in one of the little boxes."]
- The time when he invited +200 characters to his wedding. Some of them are from other comic book universes/different studios.

  [image: Deadpool stands at the baseball mound with his bride who has her face covered getting married by the Beast; the stands and the pitch are filled with various Marvel characters]
- And then there is this one. He says what the other characters are supposed to say.

  [image: DareDevil and Deadpool stand in a dark ruined building looking at each other, the latter has bullet holes in him and says: "Go on. You know you wanna say it" to which DareDevil replies "Thought you could use a hand."]
- And I think this is one of the most obvious ones that can explain your question.

  [image: Deadpool and Punisher stand talking to each other against a wall in front of a man sat cross legged with his head hanging and a pool of blood around him; Punisher says "Why'd you do that?" to which Deadpool replies "Because you were gonna do it and this is my book.", "Your what--?" "Nothing."]

**I think the characters around him would realise there is something weird going on, if he would just let them understand.**

- And one time, he just simply said it. *Deadpool Vol. 1* #34 by Christopher Priest

  [image: A doctor stands holding a clipboard looking at Deadpool who is naked hooked up to a machine with wires going onto his head, the following conversation takes place: Doctor: "You're not taking me seriously." Deadpool "Bingo. Give the man a cookie." "All right, why not?" "Well, it's a secret, really. One I've never told anyone. Something I know but you don't" "And that is--?" "If I told you, it wouldn't be much of a secret, now would it?" "Fine" "All right -- you dragged it out of me! The secret is--"] [image: Close up of Deadpool's face and a continuation of the conversation from the previous image; Deadpool "...None of this is actually happening. There is a man. At a typewriter. This is all his twisted imagination." Doctor "And you truly believe that?"]

Comment: Props to you, the first image here is the incident I was thinking of! The others are nice. I do think that most characters just think Deadpool is actually insane. Maybe they know he thinks he's in a comic book, but that's part of his psychosis, to them.

Comment: @CreationEdge Probably but we can never know, that's the best part. Even if he would explain, no one would believe.

Comment: @CreationEdge: But in reality he is the only one who isn't insane.... Oh no he is aware of us... Is he going to get me, the next time I open my book of him? :x

Comment: @Zaibis - Now you sound like you're reading [The Monster at the End of this Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monster_at_the_End_of_This_Book:_Starring_Lovable,_Furry_Old_Grover) (which of course also breaks the 4th wall nearly every page. Sometimes literally).

Comment: I don't think the first image counts. I could narrate myself and my colleagues would react to it and tell me to shut up - but it wouldn't mean they either joined in breaking fourth wall or are confused in any way. They'd dismiss it as crazy talk, just like she did.

Comment: @Agent_L The point of the first image is the "up in one of the little boxes" comment, not the self-narration. It's referring to the comic's thought bubbles. That's definitely breaking the fourth wall.

Comment: I'm not really seeing anything that supports this as an answer though.  The wedding picture is the closest, but that can be considered a special crossover event (like Superman and Batman, but they only acknowledge the other exists when reading the morning paper).  The first one is him being goofy, there isn't enough dialog there to cross the 4th wall (if comic books exist in comic book universe then the "box" wouldn't be a unknown thing).   the DD one is just as believable in universe (I know what you are going to say), and the last one can be "This will go great in my memoir".

Comment: @ChrisHayes The point of my comment is that only Deadpool refers that that little boxes. The point is I could say about me saying in little boxes (thus breaking the fourth wall) and you would dismiss me while still staying in our world. Question was about other characters acknowledging of Deadpool's breaking of fourth wall and I stand that she did not.

Comment: @Agent_L No, the question is about another character *observing* Deadpool's behavior. From the question: *"... or being confused by his strange remarks and questioning him"*

Comment: I can't find it but there is a really cool instance where he references the exact issue and page number where he last saw a character. Edit - [found it!](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/marveldatabase/images/5/5c/DeadpoolBullseye.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20080611234544)

Comment: I don't understand where he breaks the fourth wall, or where the other character acknowledges it in the 3rd one. Care to explain that one?

Comment: Is that Darth Vader at his wedding?

Comment: @DJMcGoathem: Yeah, the third example definitely seems to be missing some context. Not having read the issue, I'm assuming that Deadpool lost a hand again or something similar, but that wouldn't necessarily make it a fourth wall break -- all it really seems to show is a shared sense of (bad) humor.

Comment: @ChrisHayes Exactly: no one is being confused or questions Deadpool. She just dismissed madman's ravings just as you would dismiss mine. *Agent L smiled as his finger hit Enter*.

Comment: The wedding picture was just a cover of that particular issue, and I have no idea where you got "characters from different universes or studios". In his real wedding, inside the issue, there were far fewer characters, and all were people he had some sort of a contact with

Comment: How can the last one possibly be breaking the fourth wall? Doesn't that apply only to reaching out into the actual, real world from within the comic? Clearly comics are not written on typewriters (unless you have a very special typewriter with drawing abilities), so there's no reference to the real world—it really is just Deadpool saying nonsense.

Answer (score 23):

In the recent movie, *Deadpool* (2016), there's a scene where Deadpool is talking to the audience and Colossus says "Who are you talking to?  There's nobody around" to which Deadpool points at the camera and says "Them, over there!"

Answer (score 19):

It happens all the time. Sometimes, he is even fairly explicit with it:

[image: Domino points a silenced pistol at Deadpool who is wearing a tuxedo over his suit; they talk: Deadpool: "So you got hired to find out why I've been going to the made-up central European country of Rumekistan." Domino: "How do you know that!?" "Geez--This is you calm, huh? I read last issue, didn't you?" "What are you talking about?" "It's a fourth wall thing! Sigh"]

Comment: If I remember correctly, this panel is from the non-canon "previously on Deadpool"-type segment at the beginning of his comics.

Comment: [Here's possibly the first canon instance of Deadpool referring to previous issues of his own comic.](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/deadpool/images/5/5c/DeadpoolBullseye.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120723154721) (Deadpool vol. 1 #28, I believe)

Answer (score 8):

<sub>*Ultimate Spider-Man* Season 2 Episode 15 Ultimate Deadpool - Funniest Scene</sub>

Deadpool breaks 4th wall, then Spidey enters his break and is confused, how that happened.

1. Deadpools breaks 4th wall

   [image: A pregnant woman sits ina hospital bed looking confused, a baby Deadpool in a nappy leaps towards the camera with a katana in heand]
2. Spidey entered Deadpool's break and is confused how, and breaks Deadpools break.

   [image: An aerial shot of Deadpool on the bed with the woman now holding two katanas looking up at 3 ninjas on leaping down onto them; Spider-Man stands to the side of the bed confused]

--

And the other way round Spider-Man sees Deadpool breaking the 4th wall, and is confused, because Deadpool is painting on his thoughts and Spider-Man sees it.

2.1.:  Spidey breaks 4th wall

[image: Blue hologram image of a armed character with a skull face mask]

2.2 - Deadpool enters Spidey's break

[image: The same image as the previous one except Deadpool is leaning in from the side drawing a red moustache on the character]

2.3 - Spidey is confused by Deadpool's entering

[image: Same image again with Deadpool out of frame again and Spider-Man in front shrugging his arms]

- out of the same episode:

3.1 Spidey breaks 4th wall

[image: Close up of Spider-Man's face]

3.2. Deadpools entered Spidey's break

[image: Close up of Spider-Man's face looking surprised to see a small Deadpool appear over his shoulder]

3.3 Spidey interacts with Deadpools's break

[image: Spider-Man webs the small Deadpool back out of frame]

Comment: The YouTube link is dead.

Answer (score 3):

In *Cable & Deadpool* (the story arc in issues 43-50, I don't know which one specifically), he references Spider-Man's deal with Mephisto, even though the deal itself completely re-wrote the timeline to the point where no other character (including Spidey) was aware of it:

[image: Spider-Man leaps into frame with Deadpool and a bunch of Venom symbiote dinosaurs; Spider-Man: "What did you do, Deadpool?" Deadpool: "What did I do? Leap in logic much? Two plus two equals five much? Assume makes an ass of u much?" "So... what did you do?" "Accidentally teleported all these dinosaurs into Midtown Manhattan. But I had nothing to do with the Venom lookalike, I swear!" Off screen: "He didn't" Spider-Man: "Great, you got sidekicks now!" Deadpool "I call them a local supporting cast, Mr. Holier-Than-Though-Fugitive-From-The-Law, Spider-Man! And I don't have to make a deal with Mephitso to have it either." "?" "Never mind."]

Answer (score 1):

She-Hulk would be the only character to get what he's doing, since she has done it many times before herself. Yes, she's also aware that she is in a comicbook.

[image: She-Hulk pulls back a purple curtain revealing Deadpool in the spotlight wearing just a vest and boxers with love hearts on them carrying his suit; she says "Whelp, it's a variant cover, so I guess it's time for a Deadpool appearance!" Deadpool: "HEY!"]

Answer (score 0):

Don't remember the issue, but one time there was a not-in-universe recap page that took the form of a talk show, and then in the actual in-universe comic later he references the recap page and the person with him at the time (who had also been on the recap page) is confused.