# Are Colossus and Negasonic Teenage Warhead aware that Deadpool is breaking the 4th wall?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

### Are Colossus and Negasonic Teenage Warhead or other characters aware that Deadpool is breaking the 4th wall?

I am not sure this is canonical, but there is a [4th Wall Awareness power](http://powerlisting.wikia.com/wiki/4th_Wall_Awareness) listed on [the Superpowers Wikia.](http://www.wikia.com/fandom)

It states,

> Users have the capacity to be aware that their Universe is false.
>   Through this, they may be able to carry out acts that, within the
>   Universe, would otherwise be impossible. Depending on the extent of
>   the user's power, one could potentially gain the powers of Reality
>   Warping and/or Omniscience within the context of their own false
>   Universe.

And we see Deapool breaking the 4th wall in front of Colossus and Negasonic Teenage Warhead, at 0:49 in this video:

So if the 4th Wall Awareness super power is canonical, are Colossus and Negasonic Teenage Warhead aware that Deadpool is breaking the 4th wall? Or do they just think he is crazy and talking to himself?

Comment: @Paulie_D, not in deadpool tag there is not.

Comment: @Paulie_D, cheers!

Comment: Just because it's canonical, doesn't mean it's happening. There's no indication in the movie that they're aware of it.

Comment: @Paulie_D, so they just think he is crazy?

Comment: Either they aren't even concious of it at all (in other words, for them it doesn't happen) or, yes, they think he's crazy.

Comment: In the comic,  his 4th wall breaking is generally assumed to be symptomatic of Deadpools mental state.

Comment: related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/119709/has-another-character-ever-observed-deadpool-breaking-the-fourth-wall

Comment: They are aware of it, but don't understand it. Colossus even says "You know I can hear you." on the bridge.

Comment: As his chewing gum in the taxi actually landed on the camera lens, and he pulled it off and cleaned the it; he isn't breaking the fourth wall, but he's actually in a movie and Colossus and Negasonic are just good actors avoiding staring at the camera

Comment: I’m not clear how your wikia link is particularly relevant. Don’t you just want to know whether Colossus and Negasonic in *Deadpool* realise he’s breaking the fourth wall? Unless the people who wrote *Deadpool* slavishly followed that particular wiki page when coming up with the story, I don’t think it’s of any particular help here.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, it 4th wall awareness, if they are aware of Deadpool breaking the 4th wall, would they then not have that power?

Comment: @KyloRen: powers aren’t usually defined in the abstract in detail, and then applied to characters across comics or movies. Colossus and Negasonic in *Deadpool* are exactly as aware of the fourth wall breaking as the writers of *Deadpool* intended them to be.